# Twitter Bootstrapを使ったレスポンシブで col-md-1 以下のサイズで表示する方法

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrapを用いてレスポンシブのサイトを構築しているのですが、
`col-md-1`ですと最低でも12分の1のサイズにしかなりません。
チェックボックス一つだけを表示する幅があれば十分なので、ギリギリまで幅を詰めたいんですが何か方法はあるでしょうか？

なければ隣のカラムの先頭にチェックボックスを表示して、元のカラムは削除する形にしようと考えています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 つ 手があると思います。

1. セルを縦に割る
2. N 列の Bootstrap を使う

---

#### 1. width 指定 50%/50% でセルを縦に割る

```html
<div id="content-row" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 content" style="background-color:gray">cell2</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 content" style="background-color:gray">cell1</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:green; padding: 0px;">
        <div style="width: 50%; background-color:red; float: left;  ">
          half
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; background-color:red; float: right; ">
          half
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 content" style="background-color:gray">cell8</div>
</div>
```

[image: Bootstrap row 2:1:0.5:0.5:8]

#### 2. N 列 の Bootstrap をビルド (N:任意整数)

全レイアウトを変更しなければならないので、オーバーキルになる可能性がありますが、Bootstrap は、コンパイル前に、グリッド数設定 (3.x 系なら `@grid-columns`) を変更することでグリッド列数を変えられます。

変更するのは、 `variables.less` の以下の部分になります。以下では、 24 列の Bootstrap を生成しようとしています。

*less/variables.less*: (抜粋)

```less
//== Grid system
//
//## Define your custom responsive grid.

//** Number of columns in the grid.
@grid-columns:              12;
//** Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.
@grid-gutter-width:         30px;
// Navbar collapse
//** Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed.
@grid-float-breakpoint:     @screen-sm-min;
//** Point at which the navbar begins collapsing.
@grid-float-breakpoint-max: (@grid-float-breakpoint - 1);
```

例えば、 グリッド列数を 24 とするには以下のようにするでしょう。

*less/variables.less*: (抜粋)

```less
//** Number of columns in the grid.
@grid-columns:              24;
//** Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.
@grid-gutter-width:         15px;
```

ビルドの流れは大体以下のような感じで。

```bash
$ wget https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip && rm master.zip
$ cd bootstrap-master/less
$ vi variables.less # ここで `@grid-columns` と、 `@grid-gutter-width` を編集
$ cd ..
$ sudo npm install
$ grunt dist
```

すると、 CSS の指定できる列番号が 24 までで、1 列の幅が 4.1% の Bootstrap が生成されます。

*dist/css/bootstrap.css*: (抜粋)

```css
...
.col-sm-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 4.16666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, ... , .col-md-24 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-md-24 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-23 {
    width: 95.83333333%;
  }
  .col-md-22 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-21 {
    width: 87.5%;
  }
  .col-md-20 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
...
```

#### 参考

- GitHub, [twbs/bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)
- StackOverflow, [How to use bootstrap with 16 or 24 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591185/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-16-or-24-columns)
- StackOverflow, [Customizing number of columns in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253088/customizing-number-of-columns-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 3):

さらに細かく分けたいところで`<div class="row">`を指定すれば、そこからまた12分割できます。
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting